# What part of Gnome Terminal handles Ctrl-C?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-terminal

I've been messing around with Gnome Terminal recently, trying to customize what happens when I press Ctrl-C (I'd like it to copy when I have text selected and send SIGINT otherwise, but that's not part of the question), but I can't seem to figure out where in the stack Ctrl-C is recognized (or where Ctrl-Shift-C is recognized if Ctrl-C is rebound, for that matter).

So, what library or program is responsible for actually handling that keyboard combination?

Answer (score 0):

For <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, the terminal emulator simply sends the single byte 0x03.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> – <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> send the bytes 0x01–0x1A (decimal 1–26), respectively; furthermore, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> is 0x00, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> is 0x1B, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> is 0x1C, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> is 0x1D, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>^</kbd> (or often simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> without Shift, assuming US keyboard layout) is 0x1E, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> (or often <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> without Shift) is 0x1F.

These bytes are interpreted and handled specially by the kernel, according to the *terminal line discipline*. Check the output of `stty -a`, it probably contains `intr = ^C` which means that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (the byte 0x03) is the interrupt character.

See the manual pages of `stty`, `termios`, `ioctl`, `ioctl_tty` and related websearch matches (including for the term "line discipline") for more details.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking about is determined to two factors;

- your (chosen) shell
- the preferences in the (Gnome) terminal

To discover what is *currently* assigned to `CTRL+C` in Gnome terminal. In an open session, choose **edit** > **preferences** > **shortcuts**

As your Login shell is concerned.; `CTRL+C` (`^C`) is almost always assigned `TERM` or `HUP` (hangup).